# Ionic Styles and Icons aren't loading after updating to Angular 17

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've just updated my Ionic Application to use Angular 17 and the latest version of Ionic Angular.  I'm not interested in utilizing any of the Ionic Standalone components or functionality yet as my application is very large and it will take time to complete that update. However, I do want to make sure I'm running the latest dependencies.

When I start my application up after updating to Angular 17 it appears as if none of the Ionic Components styles are getting loaded. The components themselves load and render, but not the style.

This is what my package.json file looks like.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.0",
    "@capacitor-community/apple-sign-in": "5.0.0",
    "@capacitor-community/facebook-login": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor-community/firebase-analytics": "^5.0.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^5.0.8",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/local-notifications": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@capgo/camera-preview": "^6.0.6",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.6.2",
    "@maskito/angular": "^1.7.0",
    "@maskito/core": "^1.7.0",
    "@maskito/kit": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "badwords-list": "^1.0.0",
    "capacitor-rate-app": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-purchase": "^13.5.0",
    "kc-capacitor-image-utils": "file:../kc-capacitor-image-utils",
    "ngx-ui-tour-ionic": "^3.0.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.0",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "swiper": "^8.4.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.0.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.6.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  },
```

This is what my angular.json build file looks like.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme/variables.scss",
              "src/global.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "5kb",
                  "maximumError": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:development"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/theme/variables.scss",
              "src/global.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
    ]
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this project runs and works perfect if I'm running Angular 16. These issues only arise when I update to Angular 17.

Furthermore if I run `ng server --configurations "production"` the styles seem to render, but there are still random Ionic components where the style is not being applied.

Comment: What steps did you do to update your project to v17?

Comment: The steps outlined here https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=16.0-17.0 along with updating all additional dependencies which needed to be updated for Angular 17.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I am having a similar issue

Comment: @AaronSaunders Yes. See my answer below. Ionic has created a mess in my opinion with they way they've implemented standalone components. Angular built out standalone so that you could slowly migrate. Ionic has decided that isn't an option for their platform, which is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came down to the fact that I was importing a third-party library that was utilizing Ionic libraries in a standalone fashion, but my application is setup to use Ionic with modules still.

The third-party library was `ngx-ui-tour-ionic`. The latest version of the library which supports Angular 17 only supports Ionic applications that are configured for standalone components.

This was causing issues with loading the correct styles, however there were no errors or any indicators that this was what the cause was.

With the way Ionic has built out their standalone functionality you have to buy into it fully because the initial bootstrapping of the application is different. So basically we are going to be forced to update to standalone before we can update to Angular 17.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Can you tell me how you resolved this? Were you able to keep ngx-ui-tour-ionic?

Answer (score 2):

As for the IonIcons, it now requires for each icon to be imported in the ts file and passed as a param to addIcons method.

```
import { chevronBack } from 'ionicons/icons'
import { addIcons } from 'ionicons'


constructor() {
   addIcons({ chevronBack })
}
```

this new way kinda sucks because if you have say 10+ icons, you need to import ALL of them. So the way I handle it:

```
import { chevronBack, cameraOutline, imageOutline, closeOutline } from 'ionicons/icons'
import { addIcons } from 'ionicons'

const IonIcons = {
  chevronBack,
  cameraOutline,
  imageOutline,
  closeOutline,
  ...,
  ...,
}


constructor() {
   addIcons(IonIcons)
}
```

Comment: I updated the question and removed this portion. The issue with the icons is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should try importing all Ionic components from `'@ionic/angular/standalone'` instead of `'@ionic/angular'`
In the context of a standalone Angular applications failing to import from `'@ionic/angular/standalone'` results in bizarre anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps for anyone using Storybook, your component needs to switch to provideIonicAngular() instead of IonicModule.forRoot()

Answer (score -1):

This same scenario happened to me, just ensure 2 things.

First add the `style` bundele inside the styles array within the `build` config parameter in `angular.json`

`node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/ionic.bundle.css`

this should work if it is not then try updating the `@ionic/angular` version to the higher version to match it with Anguler 17 (or downgrade it, what makes it work.) You can check into `@ionic/angular` releases to find out which version is suitable with Angular 17.